# django-axes modelbackend requires 'request' to authenticate

Tags: django, security, django-models, django-views, django-login

In my application i have a custom user model using django-custom-user also i'm using allauth. Django-axes registers every login attempt on admin and allauth, but i have problems with the user login.

**Login view:**

```
def user_login(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('frontend:dashboard')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            if user is not None:
                user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    user_logged_in.send(sender=CustomUser, request=request, user=user)
                    return redirect('frontend:dashboard')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, _('Incorrect email or password.'))
                    user_login_failed.send(sender=CustomUser, request=request, credentials={'username': form.cleaned_data.get('email')})
            else:
                messages.error(request, _('Incorrect email or password.'))
                user_login_failed.send(sender=CustomUser, request=request, credentials={'username': form.cleaned_data.get('email')})
            return redirect('auth:login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    data['form'] = form
    return render(request, os.path.join(settings.AUTH_TEMPLATE, 'login.html'), data)
```

When i try to login i'm getting this error:

```
axes.backends.AxesModelBackend.RequestParameterRequired: DjangoAxesModelBackend requires calls to authenticate to pass `request`
```

django axes documentation is a bit confusing and i don't understand what i have to do in solving this issue.

I have to mention this error comes only when i add `axes.backends.AxesModelBackend` to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` which is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST, request=request)   
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password, request=request)
```

and furthermore using the decorator for the Login view

```
from axes.decorators import axes_dispatch
@axes_dispatch
```

was the solution. Maybe it will help you too!

best regards